# Scala on Android: best strategy for avoiding global data?

Tags: android, scala, global-variables

Suppose you have multiple activities in an app and need to share data. A pretty common pattern for Android developers it seems is to have some sort of singleton object (optionally attached to the Application singleton), and share data globally using that. That's bad enough in Java, but looks really ugly in Scala.

For message passing you can use Intents if your data consists of primitives. But what about your main domain model? I'd like to be able pass very complex objects. It seems I might be able to do that using Parcelable serialization, but I'm not sure how fast that is (my objects are data-heavy) and if it works well with Scala? Has anybody tried this?

Another idea would be to use the "HashMap of WeakReferences to Objects" strategy where the passed messages are references -- you've still got global data but access is guarded. Maybe I can get some opinions on that too, not just from Android folk but also some Scala folk.

Comment: You can store data in `Service` (I suppose it's a very popular option in android applications), so any activity can bind and get data from it. Another idea keep data in sqlite using content provider, but in case complex domain model it will be not so convenient

Comment: I was thinking about that, but it seems if I wrap global mutable data in a Service, I still have global mutable data?

Comment: But if you won't pass data through intent between activities probably there is no another way to achieve this... If you can figure this out, please post answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this was to include the Akka library in my app, and turn the global objects into messages that are passed between activities.

It seems to work OK, but not a lot of people are using Akka on Android so far and it's difficult to find best practices. If people have any comments about this strategy, let me know.